# Mui Autocomplete - onChange is not triggered when adding option programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, autocomplete

Here is the component:

```js
export const TagInput = (props: Props) => {

  let valueBackup = []
  const [value, setValue] = useState<Array<string>>([])
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useContext(SearchContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm != "") {
      setValue(prev => [...prev, searchTerm])
      valueBackup = value
    }
  }, [searchTerm])

  return (
    <div>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        value={value}
        id="tag-dropdown"
        sx={{maxWidth: 300, marginTop: '30px'}}
        options={props.tags}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
        filterSelectedOptions
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            placeholder="Tags..."
          />
        )}
        onChange={(_, value: Array<string>) => {
          console.log("THIS SHOULD BE PRINTED")
          setValue(value)
          return props.onChange(value)
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

there is another component which just sets `searchTerm` variable. I'm expecting it to execute the piece of code inside onChange handler when searchTerm is changed and `value` variable is updated (value is its previous value + searchTerm), but it's only being executed after I remove already selected options from Autocomplete. How can I solve that or is there any better ways to update selected options in MUI Autocomplete?